# How to depend on same version of maven multi-module sibling project in a parentpom

Tags: maven

I have a maven aggregator for parent poms and static analysis configuration consisting of:

- parentpom-nocode - details of our company and internal nexus repo. Also acts as aggregator and parent for the following submodules:

  - analysisconfig - configuration for checkstyle, pmd and findbugs
  - parentpom-minimal-java
  - parentpom-full-java - two parentpoms with plugin definitions including checkstyle, pmd, findbugs.

The static analysis plugins in the parentpoms need to depend on the analysisconfig to get their configuration. Ideally, this should be the same version of analysisconfig as the parentpom.

How can I specify this in the configuration? 
${project.version} doesn't work because our implementation projects will have different versions to the parentpom. Similarly, ${project.parent.version} and similar won't work because our projects are often aggregators themselves. 
Setting it to a fixed version number doesn't really work either since these should all be released together and an aggregator (and that would be a configuration nightmare anyway).

Answer (score 0):

I seen many projects where parentpom has fixed version (without dots).
The parentpom in this case should contain slow-changing information (like org info + repo configs).
You may release it one time (technikal/meta release) and use the same version in next releases.